# Illegal argument error importing h2o model

Tags: h2o

I am trying to import a model that was trained and saved using `H2O 3.22.0.2`.

The error is as follows:

```
INFO ERROR: Server error water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException:
  Error: Illegal argument: dir of function: importModel: /home/centos/models/model_20190202_1204/DeepLearning_model_python_1549126947138_1
  Request: POST /99/Models.bin/
    data: {'dir': '/home/centos/models/model_20190202_1204/DeepLearning_model_python_1549126947138_1'}
```

The version running in the server is `h2o==3.22.0.2`.

I have run a prediction using this model file locally with no issues.

Could anyone provide any clues as to what might be going on? Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

I am attempting to load the model using `h2o.load_model(model_path)`

Comment: Did you copy the model to that directory on the server?

Comment: @TomKraljevic Yes I did. Thanks.